# GPO IE Security Zones

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, group-policy

It seems when you are trying to edit the GPO for a group of Windows Server 2003 terminal servers. Under **User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Internet Explorer Maintenance > Security > Security Zones and Content Ratings (Preference Mode)**, rather than keeping the settings that are already in there, it will take whatever setting is currently applied to your IE browser setting.

IE if you go to IE Options and change the Trusted sites to “low”, then you go to the GPO setting, it will show that setting as low, completely ignoring the setting that are already applied in the Group Policy.

Does anyone know an easier way of just making a few changes rather than having to reapply all the different settings again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found what I was looking for under Site to Zone Assignment List.
**User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > Security Page.**

Then you can edit the sections you want under there. It seems the Security Zones and Content Ratings works as intended with what I described above.